# Why does Cassandra docker image require root privileges to run?

Tags: docker, cassandra

I am using the latest Cassandra docker image. When I run it with root privileges, cqlsh is able to connect to Cassandra service as expected:

```
$ sudo docker run --name mycassandra -d cassandra:latest
$ sudo docker exec -it mycassandra bash
# cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.3 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

However, if I run docker image with normal user privileges, I get an error when using cqlsh:

```
$ docker run --name mycassandra1 -d cassandra:latest
$ docker exec -it mycassandra1 bash
# cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': 
ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: 
Connection refused")})
```

I prefer not to run docker image as sudo. Wondering why Cassandra image requires sudo privileges. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're a member of the `docker` group since you can run docker without sudo. Whether you run it with or without sudo shouldn't make a difference. The container runs as root in both cases, which you can verify by the `#` bash prompt in both cases.

What I think is happening is that you're trying to run `cqlsh` before the container has finished starting up. Check the container log and make sure you see `Startup complete` before you try running `cqlsh`.

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right. The command works after waiting for some time.